# Unable to get unpack-dependencies to run before jar:jar,

Tags: maven, dependencies, execution

I cannot get maven-dependency-plugin/unpack-dependencies to run before maven-jar-plugin/jar when running mvn clean install from the command line.

Every time, I see it running jar:jar before the unpack stuff runs, I saw in my googling some talk of adding a pre-package phase to the maven lifecycle, doesn't seem to be working thought.

Basically I want to create a single jar file containing all necessary classes (all 2600 of them). This jar gets a Manifest which enables it to be run in the manner of:

```
java -jar blah.jar
```

If I ever get it to work...

And here's the xml snippet...

```
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
         <version>2.2</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                </execution>
            </executions>
          </plugin>
    <plugin>
      <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
            <configuration>
                <archive>
                    <manifest>
                        <mainClass>archivedb.Read</mainClass>
                    </manifest>
                </archive>
            </configuration>
          </plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for all replies but I've answered my own post. Follow up replies are just confusing the issue. Thanks for your attention.

Comment: Feel free to add your solution as an answer below.

Answer (score 9):

In your original question, replace the phase with the following phase.

`<phase>prepare-package</phase>`

this will cause the jars to be extracted first. For your problem, the shade solution is better, but I will still post this here as a reference for other with similar problems where shade does not help.

The output path is set to make sure that jar's contents end up in dir that the jar:jar goal packages (target/classes).

Full plugin execution xml snippet:

```
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
            <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <executions>
                <execution>
                    <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
                    <phase>prepare-package</phase>
                    <goals>
                        <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
                    </goals>
                    <configuration>
                        <includes>**/*.class</includes>
                        <excludes>**/*.properties</excludes>
                        <outputDirectory>${project.build.outputDirectory}</outputDirectory>

                    </configuration>
                </execution>
            </executions>
        </plugin>
```

Answer (score 1):

I had similiar issue with single jar creation.
My solutions incorporates standard maven-dependency plugin with unpack goal (unpacks all dependencies during **compile** process and move it into custom **outputDirectory**.
The secret is, JAR plugin takes all from *target/classes* directory and packs as a one JAR.

That's why I defined custom **outputDirectory**. Have a look at the code below:

```
  <build>
<plugins>
  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <finalName>${project.artifactId}</finalName>
      <archive>
        <manifest>
          <mainClass>pl.company.client.Uploader</mainClass>
        </manifest>
      </archive>
    </configuration>
    <version>2.3.1</version>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
    <configuration>
      <source>1.4</source>
      <target>1.4</target>
    </configuration>
    <version>2.3.2</version>
  </plugin>

  <plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
      <execution>
        <id>unpack-dependencies</id>
        <phase>compile</phase>
        <goals>
          <goal>unpack-dependencies</goal>
        </goals>
        <configuration>
          <outputDirectory>${project.build.directory}/classes</outputDirectory>
        </configuration>
      </execution>
    </executions>
  </plugin>
</plugins>

<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
  </resource>
</resources>
```

Comment: Hi Mariusz, I solved this problem a while back but was not allowed to answer my own question. Please read the second part of my posting. There is a very reliable solution these days.

Answer (score 0):

You may run it by identifying the goal sequentially as

```
"mvn clean dependency:unpack jar:jar install"
```

I hope this may help you to achieve the requirement

Regards,

Charlee Ch.

Comment: Thanks, I was trying to get something that was a one shot solution, I've posted my answer above (well, edited my question, I'm not allowed to answer my own questions)

Comment: I'm still interested to know why that execution stuff didn't run in the correct order.

Comment: @Bryan Hunt,  I've face the similar issue with the proguard plugin before. I achieve by using the "prepare-package" phase configuration. you may see further information at http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html The prepare-package is perform any operations necessary to prepare a package before the actual packaging. This often results in an unpacked, processed version of the package. (Maven 2.1 and above)